# Unexpected behaviour with sorting option, multiple ref context and biblist (biblatex 3.0)

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I have a large bibliography file where the vast majority of entries are annotated (and annotations can (and do) contain `\cite` commands).

I have to produce a list of the annotated entries displaying the tile and the notes,  and these entries should be listed in reverse chronological order (and grouped by year).

At the end I have to create a standard bibliography including the annotated entries, the entries cited in the annotations, and  eventually `crossref` entries). The bibliography is in standard numeric format and in alphabetic order.

For the list of the annotated entries I can use a biblist (with appropriate filters, and a special driver for it):

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{ggtype}{%
    \ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{\value{anno}}
      {\section*{\printfield{year}}
         \setcounter{subsection}{0}
         \setcounter{anno}{\thefield{year}}}
      {}
    \subsection[]{\thefield{title}}
    \printfield{note} \printfield{year}
    \cite{\thefield{entrykey}}
}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{exclude}
\addtocategory{exclude}{sixth}

\DeclareBiblistFilter{ggtype}{
 \filter[type=field,filter=note]
}

\defbibenvironment{ggtype}
  {\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]} % this line is for biblatex 3.0, biber 2.0
  %{} % this line is for biblatex 2.9, biber 1.9
  {}
  {}

\newcounter{anno}
\setcounter{anno}{2016}
```

The idea is that I process the entries in two rounds. In the first round I use `\nocite{*}` to include all entries in the bibtex file, in the second round the entries are taken from information in the biblist (the drive include a command to ensure self-citation (the `\cite{\thefield{entrykey}}`  at the end of the  definition of the biblist driver) and the `\nocite{*}` is removed. I use `\IfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}{}{\nocite{*}}` to achieve this.

With `biblatex 2.9` and `biber 1.9`. I can use the following schema

```
\begin{document}

\IfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}{}{\nocite{*}}

\printbiblist[heading=none,notcategory=exclude,sorting=ydnt]{ggtype}
\printbibliography[sorting=nyt]
\end{document}
```

and then use the follow workflow: `latex->biber->latex->biber->latex`.

`Biblatex 3.0` and `biber 2.0` replaced the `sorting` option of `\printbibliography`, `\printbiblist` by  "reference contexts".  Accordingly, I the schema turns out to be:

```
\begin{document}

\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
\IfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}{}{\nocite{*}}

\printbiblist[heading=none,notcategory=exclude]{ggtype}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and also note the `\newrefcontext` in the first  argument of `\definebibenvironment`.

I can use the same workflow as the one used for `biblatex 2.9`.

Here is the "unexpected behaviour" part.  If I use

```
\usepackage[sorting=nty]{biblatex}
```

then, the workflow fails. The biblist is not printed in the second latex run, and no citations in the second round, and `biber` complains that there are no citations.  Notice that the `sorting=nty` is useless in this case (so the solution is do not use it), it is harmless with `biblatex 2.9` `biber 1.9`, but problematic with `biblatex 3.0` `biber 2.0`.

Also, after the first round, the `bbl` file is generated correctly and it is not empty.

The issue was reported to the biblatex developers but they ask to post a question to this site (and to gather ideas from other people). One suggestion was to include `\nocite{*}` in the second round  otherwise this won't be written in the `.bcf` and `biber` will not look for anything. However, `\cite` should be issued inside the biblist. While this suggestion works for the MWE (see blow for the full MWE), for the project I work on, it requires an additional `latex->biber` roundtrip.

So the question is whether the behaviour with the additional (and useless) `sorting` option is the expected one or not.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber
    sorting=nyt, % this is the problematic line; commenting it solves the problem.
]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{first,
    title = {First Title},
    author = {Author, Author},
    year = 2015,
    note = {note}
}
@book{second,
    title = {Second Title},
    author = {Duthor, Duthor},
    year = 2015,
    note = {note}
}
@book{third,
    title = {Third Title},
    author = {Buthor, Buthor},
    year = 2014,
    note = {note}
}
@book{fourth,
    title = {Fourth Title},
    author = {Cuthor, Cuthor},
    year = 2014,
    note = {note \cite{seventh}}
}
@book{fifth,
    title = {Fifth Title},
    author = {Euthor, Euthor},
    year = 2014,
}
@book{sixth,
    title = {Sixth Title},
    author = {Futhor, Futhor},
    year = 2015,
    note = {note}
}
@book{seventh,
    title = {Seventh Title},
    author = {Guthor, Guthor},
    year = 2014,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{ggtype}{%
    \ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{\value{anno}}
      {\section*{\printfield{year}}
         \setcounter{subsection}{0}
         \setcounter{anno}{\thefield{year}}}
      {}
    \subsection[]{\thefield{title}}
    \printfield{note} \printfield{year}
    \cite{\thefield{entrykey}}
}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{exclude}
\addtocategory{exclude}{sixth}

\DeclareBiblistFilter{ggtype}{
 \filter[type=field,filter=note]
}

\defbibenvironment{ggtype}
  % comment/uncomment the following wto line for biblatex 3.0 and 2.9
  {\newrefcontext[sorting=nty]} % 3.0
  %{} % 2.9
  {}
  {}

\newcounter{anno}
\setcounter{anno}{2016}

\begin{document}

% comment /uncomment the following line for biblatex 2.9/3.0
\newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt] % 3.0

\IfFileExists{\jobname.bbl}{}{\nocite{*}}

% comment the following two lines for biblatex 2.9
\printbiblist[heading=none,notcategory=exclude]{ggtype}
\printbibliography

% uncomment the following two lines for biblatex 2.9
%\printbiblist[heading=none,notcategory=exclude,sorting=ydnt]{ggtype}
%\printbibliography[sorting=nty]
\end{document}
```

[image]