# Automatically citing all entries with keyword

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way with biblatex to automatically cite all papers with a certain keyword or from a certain resource, while keeping the original citation order and adding the uncited publications at the end?

The usual way, i.e. with `\nocite{*}`, includes all resources, which is definitely not wanted and would include `other1` in the example below. Putting a `\nocite{*}` in a `refsection`, the citation markers are not related to the main text.

```
\begin{refsection}{lib-own.bib}
  \nocite{*}
\end{refsection}
\printbibliography[...,section=1]
```

---

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[style=phys,biblabel=brackets,pageranges=false,backend=biber,sorting=none,defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{lib-own.bib}
@article{own1,
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {First pub},
    year = {1993},
    keywords = {mypub}
}

@article{own2, 
    author = {John Doe},
    title = {Second pub},
    year = {1994},
    keywords = {mypub}
}

\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{lib-other.bib}
  @article{other1,
    author = {Otto Maler},
    title = {First ref},
    year = {1993}
  }

  @article{other2, 
    author = {Peter Schuster},
    title = {Second ref},
    year = {1994}
  }

\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{lib-own.bib}
\addbibresource{lib-other.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{own1}\cite{other2}

\printbibliography[keyword={mypub},heading=subbibliography,prefixnumbers=S,title=publications]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=mypub,heading=subbibliography,resetnumbers=true,title=references]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not supported at the moment and due to technical limitations is unlikely to be supported in the future. See the duplicate (I'd say) [Is it possible to add entries to the bibliography based on keyword using Biblatex/Biber and within the document code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258888/35864). In certain scenarios it is possible to work around this limitation with some tricks, but that depends on your exact needs.

Comment: Would you agree that your question is a duplicate of the one I linked to above?

Comment: @moewe Thanks for this (negative) answer. I think the question is not quite a duplicate, because in their case, a `\nocite{*}` seems to be a solution, but they are not satisfied, because the `.bbl` would be too huge. However, I guess, if there is a solution, it would answer both questions.

Comment: But you can't use `\nocite` either, right? I don't see any practical difference between the two.

Comment: @moewe I could use a `\nocite{key1,key2...}` but this could get tedious after some publications. `\nocite{*}` is not possible because of the other references. I'm fine with tagging it as duplicate. However, I didn't succeed in doing so, because I can't find the linked question in the dialog...

Comment: Exactly my point. I didn't manage to close your question as a duplicate either, because the other question doesn't have an answer yet.