# Can I make "citetitles" (note the plural) cite all entries in a book?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber, multiple-citations

Consider this MWE (to be run with `xelatex`, `biber`, `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{poe1907hemmelighedsfulde,
title = {Hemmelighedsfulde Fortællinger},
author = {Poe, Edgar Allan},
year = {1907},
publisher = {Gyldendal},
}
@inbook{poe1907mysteriet,
title = {Mysteriet Marie Rogêt},
crossref = {poe1907hemmelighedsfulde},
}

@inbook{poe1907guldbillen,
title = {Guldbillen},
crossref = {poe1907hemmelighedsfulde},
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

The book \citetitle{poe1907hemmelighedsfulde} contains \citetitles{poe1907mysteriet,poe1907guldbillen}.

\end{document}
```

Is is possible to do something like this instead?

```
The book \citetitle{poe1907hemmelighedsfulde} contains \citealltitles{poe1907hemmelighedsfulde}.
```

Comment: Interesting question: The information which entries `crossref` `poe1907hemmelighedsfulde` is not available to `biblatex` out of the box. Additionally you would not know that all entries that `crossref` `poe1907hemmelighedsfulde` are really `@inbook`s (i.e. chapters/other units of the `@book` `poe1907hemmelighedsfulde`), so even if there was such a list, it would have to be filtered.

Comment: This question is obscure as long as you're not making a list of short story collections ... But when you are, you could really need this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex` does not have a list of entries that `crossref` a particular parent entry. So when we process `poe1907hemmelighedsfulde` we have no way of knowing its children.

That means that a first step to solving this problem is to obtain its children. This happens in the `\AtDataInput` below: For each entry with `crossref` the list `\knblx@crossrefs@<refsection>@for@<entrykey>` will contain its children. The fact that this happens on a `biblatex` level in `\AtDataInput` implies a very important limitation: **Children are only detected if they appear in the `.bbl` file, i.e. when they are explicitly `\cite`d or if they are added to the `.bbl` with `\nocite`.** It is unlikely that this limitation could be overcome even if the list of entries were provided by Biber out of the box, since that would require that each entry in the `.bib` - cited or not - would have to be examined and read (related: [Is it possible to add entries to the bibliography based on keyword using Biblatex/Biber and within the document code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258888/35864)).

If you have that list of children, implementing a `\citeallcontainedtitles` is 'just' a matter of looping over the list and printing the desired information. Since it is not guaranteed in general that a `crossref`-ing entry has the "in" relationship to its parent, the command as implemented in the MWE checks that this is the case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}

\makeatletter
\AtDataInput{%
  \iffieldundef{crossref}
    {}
    {\listcsxadd{knblx@crossrefs@\the\c@refsection @for@\thefield{crossref}}{\thefield{entrykey}}}}

% {<loopcode>}{<entrytype> (* applies to all types)}{<entry key>}
\newcommand*{\knlbx@filteredloop}[3]{%
  \edef\knblx@thisentrytype{#2}%
  \entrydata{#3}{%
    \ifstrequal{#2}{*}
      {#1}
      {\expandafter\ifentrytype\expandafter{\knblx@thisentrytype}
         {#1}
         {}}}}

\newbibmacro{citeallcontainedtitles}{%
  \ifcsvoid{knblx@crossrefs@\the\c@refsection @for@\thefield{entrykey}}
    {\blx@nounit}
    {\forlistcsloop
       {\knlbx@filteredloop
          {\usebibmacro{kncite:title}%
           \setunit{\addcomma\space}}
          {in\thefield{entrytype}}}
       {knblx@crossrefs@\the\c@refsection @for@\thefield{entrykey}}}}

\newbibmacro{kncite:title}{%
  \ifciteindex
    {\indexfield{indextitle}}
    {}%
  \printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}}
\makeatother

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeallcontainedtitles}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeallcontainedtitles}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{poe1907hemmelighedsfulde,
  title     = {Hemmelighedsfulde Fortællinger},
  author    = {Poe, Edgar Allan},
  year      = {1907},
  publisher = {Gyldendal},
}
@inbook{poe1907mysteriet,
  title    = {Mysteriet Marie Rogêt},
  crossref = {poe1907hemmelighedsfulde},
}
@inbook{poe1907guldbillen,
  title    = {Guldbillen},
  crossref = {poe1907hemmelighedsfulde},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\nocite{*}

\begin{document}
The book \citetitle{poe1907hemmelighedsfulde} contains \citeallcontainedtitles{poe1907hemmelighedsfulde}.
\end{document}
```

[image: The book Hemmelighedsfulde Fortællinger contains “Guldbillen,” “Mysteriet Marie Rogêt.”]

Comment: Phew! I'm surprised this stuff is not trivial!

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard To be honest the code is probably a bit more complicated than necessary for your specific situation (I'm thinking about the type check here). It often is the case that certain things are complicated because no one thought about implementing them and no one asked for them yet. Feel free to open a feature request at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues if you think some of this should be supported natively.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, but it may be an obscure request.