# How to restrict \nocite to certain reference segments

Tags: biblatex

I have split my bibliography thematically in several reference *segments* at the end of my article. I would like to use `\nocite` locally inside some of the segment environments, but that seems not possible with `\refsegment`, it still acts globally. Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart} 

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    %heading = references,
    citestyle=alphabetic,
    bibstyle=alphabetic,
    sorting=anyvt,
    backref=true,
    backrefstyle=none,
    locallabelwidth=true
    ]{biblatex}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm} 

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Ahl,
author = {Ahlfors, L. V.},
title = {Complex Analysis, An Introduction to the Theory of Analytic Functions of One Complex Variable},
edition = {3},
publisher = {McGraw-Hill},
year = {1979},
keywords = {complex analysis}
}

@Book{BerGay,
author = {Berenstein, C. A. and Gay, R.},
title = {Complex Variables, An Introduction},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {1991},
keywords = {complex analysis}
}

@Book{AM,
author = {Atiyah, M. F. and MacDonald, I. G.},
title = {Introduction to Commutative Algebra},
publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
year = {1969},
keywords = {Algebra}
}

@Book{HoffKun,
author = {Hoffman, K. and Kunze, R.},
title = {Linear Algebra},
publisher = {Prentice-Hall},
edition = {2},
year = {1971},
keywords = {Algebra}
}

@Book{GrRem,
author = {Grauert, H. and Remmert, R.},
title = {Coherent Analytic Sheaves},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {1984}
}

@Book{Loday,
author = {Loday, J.-L.},
title = {Cyclic Homology},
publisher = {Springer},
year = {1998},
edition = {2}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Ahl}, \cite{AM}, \cite{GrRem} are great books. 

\begin{refsegment}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword={complex analysis},title={References on Complex Analysis}]   
\end{refsegment}

\begin{refsegment}
    \printbibliography[keyword={Algebra},title={References on Algebra}] 
\end{refsegment}

\printbibliography[notkeyword={complex analysis},notkeyword={Algebra},title={Other References}]

\end{document}
```

I know that `\nocite` behaves locally with `\refsection`, but I don't want to split  my .bib file in various different .bib files, and moreover, the biblatex manual says that `\refsegment` is the intended environment for my case :-) Indeed `\refsection` behaves a little funky when I use the same .bib file for different reference sections.

An ugly workaround would be to group together all `\nocite` reference segments *after* the no-`\nocite` reference segments, but this breaks the logical order of the topics.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Mmh, that's interesting, I report I can reproduce the described behavior. I'm not sure it is expected. But, alas, I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Since `refsegment`s basically just add a marker (much like a keyword) to an entry and otherwise don't change anything it is sort of expected that `\nocite{*}` would add all entries. In fact I have a hard time figuring out how a local `\nocite{*}` should work, but I might be missing something (are you using `\nocite` with an argument different from `*`, i.e. a `\nocite{sigfridsson}`?). A short example document (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/3586 or https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) might help me understand what is going on in more detail.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks for the reply! No, I am just using the standard `\nocite{*}` in basic `amsart` or `report`, see my edit. Do you still need me to include a full MWE?

Comment: Yes, please include a full MWE. I'm still struggling to understand what exactly you are after. In your example a normal `\cite{sigfridsson}` should behave exactly the same as a `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: @moewe How so? If a refsegment works like a marker, why should a `\nocite`d entry show up in the bibliography of another refsegment? (And it does https://gist.github.com/gusbrs/ba5686c28efc631343c9a128061c9707).

Comment: @gusbrs It's a marker that is not evaluated or acted upon by default, cf. https://gist.github.com/moewew/5d73e4b075e9332f65cd5c1a159feb3f

Comment: @gusbrs That is to say the OP could probably get what they ask for with `segment=\therefsegment`, but I don't know whether that is really what they want or need and I don't understand why the question only asks about `\nocite` when a normal `\cite` has the same effect. (Of course that could be explained if the OP simply does not use `\cite`...)

Comment: @moewe Ah, I get your point. Indeed `segment=\therefsegment` was the missing piece here. Thanks. That likely is also the solution for the OP, but indeed, more info is needed to know for sure.

Comment: @moewe: finished adding a MWE, I hope I have not forgotten anything important. I have cited one reference from each group, yet all six references are listed in the bibliography, while I would like only the first group of references to be listed in the full. I hope I am explaining that well. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The MWE was almost good, I had to change a few things to make it compilable (the name of the `.bib` file should not be `\references.bib`). I also removed the title of the paper, because it is not important. I also changed `algebra` to `Algebra`, so the second bibliography would print something. Please always test your MWEs in a new, empty directory before you send them off. What output would you want from your MWE? What should be different? For me the MWE already looks quite sensible: No entry appears twice, everything is sorted as expected ...

Comment: @moewe A comment on "not evaluated or acted upon by default". The documentation for `\printbibliography` states for `segment` the `default: 0` which is supposed to mean "outside a refsegment environment" and not quite "not acted upon".

Comment: @gusbrs Mhhh, I guess that's a lie, my tests seem to suggest otherwise. I hope I can investigate this later, but if I forget, feel free to open a bug report to remind me.

Comment: @moewe: oops, thanks for fixing the mwe. Under "References on Algebra" and "Other References" only the cited references should appear. Yet all references from the .bib file appear there because `\nocite` acts globally spreading outside of the first `refsegment`. So how do I fix that?

Comment: Aha! Now I understand.

Comment: @moewe If I grasp this correctly, probably what's going on is the following. `refsegment` is useful when we need a global bibliography alongside separated ones. The option `segment` in `printbibliography` is an integer. `0` may really be the default, but if so it is somehow hardwired to mean "all refsegments", because that's what we need for a global bibliography. Implicitly, to get the global bibliography, `segment` has to be ommited. If an option `segment=all` existed, the default could be, more naturally, `segment=\therefsegment`. I'm guessing here... But, ok, more on github, if need be.

Comment: @gusbrs The default is not `segment=0`, instead the default is nothing at all. Similar to, say, filtering by `type=` or `category=`. I have changed the docs (I'm currently in the process of tweaking the docs on a larger scale, so this change might be committed a little later with the other changes I have lined up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `refsegment`s only add a marker to entries (much like `keywords` or `category`), it does not do much more. By default `biblatex` does not even evaluate the marker, so an entry `\nocite{*}`/`\nocite`'d in one `refsegment` will naturally appear in all other segments as well.

If you want to restrict a `\printbibliography` to one `refsegment`, you have to use the `segment` option. This might work as follows

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart} 
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=alphabetic,
    sorting=anyvt,
    backref=true,
    backrefstyle=none,
    locallabelwidth=true
    ]{biblatex}

\newrobustcmd{\mklocalfilter}[1]{%
  \defbibfilter{#1}{%
    segment=0
    or
    segment=\therefsegment
  }}    

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Ahl,
  author = {Ahlfors, L. V.},
  title = {Complex Analysis, An Introduction to the Theory of Analytic Functions of One Complex Variable},
  edition = {3},
  publisher = {McGraw-Hill},
  year = {1979},
  keywords = {complex analysis}
}
@book{BerGay,
  author = {Berenstein, C. A. and Gay, R.},
  title = {Complex Variables, An Introduction},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {1991},
  keywords = {complex analysis}
}
@book{AM,
  author = {Atiyah, M. F. and MacDonald, I. G.},
  title = {Introduction to Commutative Algebra},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1969},
  keywords = {algebra}
}
@book{HoffKun,
  author = {Hoffman, K. and Kunze, R.},
  title = {Linear Algebra},
  publisher = {Prentice-Hall},
  edition = {2},
  year = {1971},
  keywords = {algebra}
}
@book{GrRem,
  author = {Grauert, H. and Remmert, R.},
  title = {Coherent Analytic Sheaves},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {1984}
}
@book{Loday,
  author = {Loday, J.-L.},
  title = {Cyclic Homology},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {1998},
  edition = {2}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{Ahl}, \cite{AM}, \cite{GrRem} are great books. 

\begin{refsegment}
\mklocalfilter{nocitelocal}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword={complex analysis},filter=nocitelocal,title={References on Complex Analysis}]   
\end{refsegment}

% only cited entries, please
\printbibliography[keyword={algebra},segment=0,title={References on Algebra}] 

% only cited entries, please
\printbibliography[notkeyword={complex analysis},notkeyword={algebra},segment=0,title={Other References}]
\end{document}
```

[image: The MWE shows three citations and three bibliographies. The first bibliography contains both cited and uncited entries, while the other two bibliographies only have cited entries.]

Note that `segment=0` applies to all entries *outside* a specific `refsegment` and that the bibfilter `nocitelocal` is defined locally directly in the `refsegment` in order to use the variable `\therefsegment`.

In this setup all entries that were explicitly `\cite`'d were cited in `section=0`, but `\nocite{*}` happened in `segment=1`. Hence restricting a bibliography to `segment=0` gives all cited entries, allowing the current segment as well gives a way to locally `\nocite{*}` all entries.

---

If we look at your problem from a different angle though, it seems to me more natural to reformulate it as follows: How can I `\nocite` only entries with a certain keyword? Unfortunately, as [Is it possible to add entries to the bibliography based on keyword using Biblatex/Biber and within the document code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258888/35864) and other questions on this site show, there is no universal way to do that. One has to find sly workarounds.

In your case we can apply [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864) and come up with

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,reqno]{amsart} 

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    %heading = references,
    style=alphabetic,
    sorting=anyvt,
    backref=true,
    backrefstyle=none,
    locallabelwidth=true
    ]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{cited}
\AtEveryCitekey{\addtocategory{cited}{\thefield{entrykey}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Ahl,
  author = {Ahlfors, L. V.},
  title = {Complex Analysis, An Introduction to the Theory of Analytic Functions of One Complex Variable},
  edition = {3},
  publisher = {McGraw-Hill},
  year = {1979},
  keywords = {complex analysis}
}
@book{BerGay,
  author = {Berenstein, C. A. and Gay, R.},
  title = {Complex Variables, An Introduction},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {1991},
  keywords = {complex analysis}
}
@book{AM,
  author = {Atiyah, M. F. and MacDonald, I. G.},
  title = {Introduction to Commutative Algebra},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  year = {1969},
  keywords = {algebra}
}
@book{HoffKun,
  author = {Hoffman, K. and Kunze, R.},
  title = {Linear Algebra},
  publisher = {Prentice-Hall},
  edition = {2},
  year = {1971},
  keywords = {algebra}
}
@book{GrRem,
  author = {Grauert, H. and Remmert, R.},
  title = {Coherent Analytic Sheaves},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {1984}
}
@book{Loday,
  author = {Loday, J.-L.},
  title = {Cyclic Homology},
  publisher = {Springer},
  year = {1998},
  edition = {2}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}
\begin{document}
\cite{Ahl}, \cite{AM}, \cite{GrRem} are great books. 

% all entries, cited and uncited
\printbibliography[keyword={complex analysis},title={References on Complex Analysis}]   

% only cited entries, please
\printbibliography[keyword={algebra},category=cited,title={References on Algebra}] 

% only cited entries, please
\printbibliography[notkeyword={complex analysis},notkeyword={algebra},category=cited,title={Other References}]
\end{document}
```

[image: The screenshot of the MWE shows three bibliographies. The first contains one cited and an uncited entry. The other two bibliographies only contain cited entries.]