# biblatex keyword not found

Tags: biblatex

Why does `biblatex` warn that

```
Keyword 'additional' not found on input line 33.
```

and, accordingly, not print the second bibliography?

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@Article{EulerE,
  author = {Euler, Leonhard},
  title = {All about E},
  journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},
  year = {1776},
  volume = {4},
  pages={1--2718},
  keywords={cited},
}
@Book{BourbakiPure,
  author={Bourbaki, Nicolas},
  title={A Course of Very Pure Mathematics},
  year={1956},
  publisher={Erehwon Press},
  address={Paris},
  keywords={additional},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\textcite{EulerE} studied the constant $e$.

\printbibliography[keyword=cited,title=Cited Works]
\printbibliography[keyword=additional,title=Additional References]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

`biblatex` (and indeed also classical BibTeX) only considers entries that were cited. If you want to add an entry to the bibliography without citing it, you can use `\nocite{<key>}`. With `\nocite{*}` you add all entries from your `.bib` files to the bibliography.

Note that it is not easily possible to `\nocite` only entries with a particular `keyword`: [Is it possible to add entries to the bibliography based on keyword using Biblatex/Biber and within the document code?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258888/35864). Workarounds might be possible in certain situations, but they can not satisfy all desiderata.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=numeric, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{EulerE,
  author = {Euler, Leonhard},
  title = {All about E},
  journal = {Math.\ Psychol.},
  year = {1776},
  volume = {4},
  pages={1--2718},
  keywords={cited},
}
@Book{BourbakiPure,
  author={Bourbaki, Nicolas},
  title={A Course of Very Pure Mathematics},
  year={1956},
  publisher={Erehwon Press},
  address={Paris},
  keywords={additional},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
\textcite{EulerE} studied the constant $e$.

\printbibliography[keyword=cited,title=Cited Works]
\nocite{BourbakiPure}
\printbibliography[keyword=additional,title=Additional References]
\end{document}
```

[image: Euler [1] studied the constant e.//Cited Works//[1] Leonhard Euler. “All about E”. In: Math. Psychol. 4 (1776), pp. 1–2718.//Additional References//[2] Nicolas Bourbaki. A Course of Very Pure Mathematics. Paris: Erehwon Press, 1956.]

Since you have a numeric split bibliography, you should look into using `defernumbers=true` to make sure the numbering is increasing.

---

You may be interested in a more automatic solution for a 'works cited'/'further reading' split bibliography setup: [How to split bibliography into "works cited" and "works not cited"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6967/35864).