# Is there a way to use \nocite to print all references with a certain keyword?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have a large database of references and I would like to print all uncited references that are tagged with a certain keyword. How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: How about you create a small version of your large database and include it in a minimal example so we can play around with your request. See [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764) Can you do that?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not something Biber can do. As far as I understand this is a fundamental limitation of the way it parses `.bib` entries. Duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258888/35864

Comment: In certain situations it might be possible to find an acceptable workaround, but in general this feature is simply not available.

Comment: @moewe, what a good answer in that question!

Comment: @DavidPurton Quite. Apparently Koalas are good at Perl.

Comment: Would you agree that your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258888/35864?

Comment: I am considering a sourcemap feature which allows matching of entries which were explicitly cited only - I think this might help solve your problem - see my tentative answer to the old https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258888/35864

Comment: See the referenced duplicate for a solution using biber 2.14/biblatex 3.14. This should be possible now. biber has had access to the required information during data parsing for quite some time but for some reason I never made this visible to the user through sourcemap verbs.